# Excel - Double press of the Fill Handle is filling to the end of column, not the end of adjacent dataset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, fill

**Summary:**

I am currently trying to fill a formula to a whole column in Excel to the end of an adjacent dataset (`A2:A14500`). Instead of the usual behaviour where Excel will flash-fill it to the end of the dataset in the adjacent column `B2:B14500` for example, it instead flash fills it to the whole column (`B2:B1048576`), even past the end of the dataset in column A.

**Use Case:**

Column A is just a =`FILTER` command to pull from another sheet, excluding the blanks (in my live sheet, cell `A1` is `=FILTER('Raw'!A:A,'Raw'!A:A<>"")`. All other columns contain headers in cell `1:1`. Cell `B2` contains a basic 2 part `=IF` statement with an error catchall: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'Lookup'!A:B,2,FALSE)),"No",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'Lookup'!A:B,2,FALSE)="Error","Yes","No"))`

In my current example, the `=FILTER` in column A produces 14500 rows of data. I am attempting to use the fill handle to populate `B3:B14500` with the `=IF` statement currently in cell `B2`. When I double press the fill handle, it fills the whole column of `B3:B1048576`, which causes Excel to crash (I am trying to do the same for 32 columns (`B2:AG14500`), so it is flash-filling over 33 million formulas instead of 600K).

**Expected result when double clicking flash handle in formula column:**

| Data | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 | No |
| 4 | Yes |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |

**Actual current result when double clicking flash handle in formula column:**

| Data | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 | No |
| 4 | Yes |
|  | No |
|  | No |
|  | No |
|  | No |
|  | No |

**Final Comment:**

Usually, when double pressing the fill handle on a formula in column B, I'd expect it to match the end of the dataset in column A (If column A contains data in cells `A2:A100`, I'd expect double pressing a formula in cell `B2` to copy that formula to `B2:B100`, not `B2:B1048576`).

I know that copy-pasting is an option, as is manually dragging the fill handle down, but this involves me using weird Ctrl/Shift/Arrowkey combos to select the right range (this is supposed to be user friendly by others who don't use Excel much), or a long time holding the fill handle as there's 14K rows of data. Additionally, I am aware of **Home>Fill>Down** and **Data>Flash Fill** but neither of these work for me (Fill Down replaces the formula in `B2` with the header in `B1` and only copies down to `B2`, and Flash Fill tells me it can't see a pattern, despite providing it 1/2/5/10 cells of example data).

Any assistance with understanding why the double-click fill handle isn't working (I suspect it's due to the way it handles the `=FILTER` in column A), or how to overcome this would be appreciated. Currently using MSO365. Thanks!

PS. The reason I haven't filled the formulas manually is the number of cells in column A will change for each report generated with this spreadsheet, so the number of cells it needs to populate will vary.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. When you say "*the =FILTER in column A produces 14500 rows of data*", can you confirm that the blue border surrounding the FILTER spill range ends at this row?

Comment: I can confirm the blue border spill range ends at the end. See here: https://i.imgur.com/aR6uqRP.png Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. And what does the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(0+ISBLANK(A14948:A1048576))` return for you? The 14948 is based on your screenshot and is intended to be the first cell after your spill range. Amend as necessary.

Comment: @JosWoolley - the result of the formula is 1033629, so it does indeed think all the cells are blank, but still flash-fills to the end of the column despite this.

Comment: What's the last-used cell in the worksheet, i.e. what row is active after you perform CTRL+END?

Comment: It believes the last cell is BD1048576. This is despite me manually selecting `A2:BD1048576` then pressing Delete to clear the contents. I've also tried manually deleting rows `14948:1048576` and deleting columns `BD:XFD`, to no avail.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/clean-excess-cell-formatting-on-a-worksheet-e744c248-6925-4e77-9d49-4874f7474738

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2#,'Lookup'!A:B,2,FALSE)),"No",IF(VLOOKUP(A2#,'Lookup'!A:B,2,FALSE)="Error","Yes","No"))`

Adding `#` to the cell range that results in the spill will reference the whole spill. In case of lookup it'll spill the result of the lookups from the first to the last of the cells from the spill range.

PS since you own Office 365 you might want to look into `XLOOKUP` instead of `VLOOKUP`. `XLOOKUP` already has an embedded `value if not found`.